# How to send a notice to the users who have my App installed?

Tags: android, google-play

Before, I deployed an App on the Google Play market. After several months, there are like 100 users are using it. Recently, I found a bug in that version of App, so I created a fixed version and push it to my Google Play Console.

However, I noticed some users are still using the old version. Is there anyway that I can notice those users that **"there is a serious bug in that version, please update it to the latest one"**?

Comment: No you cannot. You can make your own notification system from this new version onwards if you want. It's the users' loss anyway. If they discover the bug they'll update or complain to you (email/review) and you reply telling them to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry but there is no way you can notify them. Google will notify them of the new version of your app but they can chose not to update it.

Like A-C said, you should implement a notification system to inform them of this, i would suggest using http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

But this will only help you with your next versions...